# Is there an alternative to the Geometry -> Normal Output?

Tags: node-editor, normals, displacement, mathematics, procedural

This is the matte I need, created from the mesh with this ring displacement using the "normal" output. I will be using a different displacement in the end but I need this specific information. I am making a fully procedural material and want to avoid baking this texture. I could just manually make circles where they are here but I'd rather use this idea so I don't have to manually change them later if I need too. Is there some way of locking this texture to stay how it is now or is there an alternative node with a similar effect? I just want a matte that's white where the outside and inside wall of this displaced ring would be.

[image]

Comment: First time using blender stack exchange, sorry for the symbol brap at the beginning and whatnot

Comment: I want a texture on top of the ring but since the rings sides aren't completely vertical (an intentional design) If I use the texture that the ring is using then the texture i want on top will show up on the sides, so i want this matte so i can subtract it from the top texture so it does not show up on the sides. When i use this matte from the Geometry node, it works, but then when i put it into the displacement the whole mesh updates and the matte changes (as expected).

Comment: Have you tried the normal output of the "texture coordinate" node ?

Comment: Same Story, I've settled with just doing it by hand which isn't too bad. Does the job well

Answer (score 1):

Taking the dot-product of the *Normal* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node with `(0,0,1)` will return the Z component of the surface normals, in Object space.

[image]

This ring has a curved profile on the inside, and is tapered on the outside.

This discrimination is good.. if you had displacements on the curved surfaces which resulted in |Z| = 1 normals, you could further discriminate by absolute Z location in *Generated* texture space...

[image]

Either way.. or both ?

Comment: .. or just strip out the Z with separate XYZ, .. force of habit..